# How to select h4 heading

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to decrease my font size for a h4 header and change some other things but the h4 class, `.awpcp-listing-title` doesn't seem to function as a selector.

Tried several options, including `important`, like the code I have here:

```css
.awpcp-listing-title {
    font-size: 10px; 
    margin-right: 50px; 
    padding: 15px;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
        <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/28/scarf/london/uk/barnet/clothes/">Scarf</a></h4>
        <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-content">Grey scarf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
        05/10/2019<br/>
```

Comment: `.awpcp-listing-title` should function as a valid selector, though you may have rules that are overriding it. You may need to increase the specificity; try a selector like `.awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner > .awpcp-listing-title`.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to function" isn't a very good problem statement.  I'm _strongly_ guessing that it's a fine selector, but if you used your developer tools to see the styles that are being applied, you likely have a [specificity](https://medium.com/@dte/understanding-css-selector-specificity-a02238a02a59) issue.

Comment: Your sample code is missing the dot at the beginning indicating it is a class. It should be `.awpcp-listing-title { .... }` and you can increase specificity by doing something like `h4.awpcp-listing-title { ... }`

Comment: @ObsidianAge That worked, but now I've got these container boxes that refuse to disappear - https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/

Comment: @ObsidianAge also, how do I change the title to break up into two separate text lines? Can i do it with `display`?

Answer (score 0):

```
.awpcp-listing-title {font-size: 10px !important;}
```

the !important is very "important" to make sure your CSS will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the CSS code slightly. No need to include the URL selector.

```
h4.awpcp-listing-title {
    font-size: 10px!important;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.awpcp-listing-title a 
{
  font-size: 10px!important;
  margin-right: 50px; 
  padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
        <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/28/scarf/london/uk/barnet/clothes/">Scarf</a></h4>
        <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-content">Grey scarf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
        05/10/2019<br/>
```

Check and try this code

Answer (score 0):

```css
h4.awpcp-listing-title{
font-size:20px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner">
        <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/28/scarf/london/uk/barnet/clothes/">Scarf</a></h4>
        <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-content">Grey scarf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
        05/10/2019<br/>
</div>
```

remove style="w" incorrect stansted code

Answer (score 0):

**You really should not use !important** as all the other answers suggest - you simply need to find the right selector and it is is NOT the `h4` - its the `a` within it.

Simply put - browers render h4's with default styling, so first - clear that using the h4 element as the selector - then target its child - the `a` element.

I have styled it red to show that it is targetted.

```css
h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

.awpcp-listing-title a {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-right: 50px; 
  padding 15px;
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
        <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title">
        <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/28/scarf/london/uk/barnet/clothes/">Scarf</a>
        </h4>
        <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-content">Grey scarf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
        05/10/2019<br/>
```

Comment: Already this answer was suggested..Please try to read the answers posted before

Comment: @UIDeveloper - wih respect - when I posted this - the only answers were the ones that sugggested the use of !Important and did not target the a within the h4. Please try to understand that sometimes several dev's work on the same solution and at roughly the same time. I do actualyl try to ensure that i don't simply replicate other's answers and if another has posted a responnse the same as or very similar to mine - I will remove ine. But I stand by this post - not only becasue at the time, there was no directly similar answers - but also becuae theanswers provided used the wrong approach  IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind your code is not working is that you are using anchor tag and your css has no code to change that font-size.

```css
.awpcp-listing-title a{ 
   font-size: 10px; 
   margin-right: 50px; 
   padding :  15px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
        <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/28/scarf/london/uk/barnet/clothes/">Scarf</a></h4>
        <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-content">Grey scarf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
        05/10/2019<br/>
```